# Crash when using loadNibNamed

Tags: swift, uikit, uistoryboard, xib

This is my code:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    let mainBundle = Bundle.main
    mainBundle.loadNibNamed("iconView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
}
```

I copied it from step 8 in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960) that I've seen (I only changed the name in the code to my xib file: "iconView").
**But for some reason it fails:**
[image: fail]
I already tried all of the solutions in stackoverflow, but nothing helped me.
Here is my xib file:
[image: xib file]
I really don't know what to do.
I'm using Xcode 12 beta 6, iOS 14 beta 6
**UPDATE**
Okay, a lot of people saied in the comments of the tutorial that

> This causes an infinite-loop calling commonInit().

So now I know what the issue is, but I still don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of the view? I bet you have also set it to be `iconView`. Note that *only* the owner should be `iconView`. The view itself should be just `UIView` (or `UIImageView` or whatever view type you are using).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to remove Class from your View.

First select your `View` (in your case `iconView`):

[image]

and then clear whatever there is in the `class` field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. After I did that, I got an error with the outlets, but fortunately I knew how to fix it, and it's all working perfect now. Thank you, again!

Comment: @אוריorihpt How you have resolved outlet issue?